# Hide React-Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using React-Select because of its ability to enable users to filter the dropdown as they type. I need to add another functionality whereby based on another value of a dropdown, the next dropdown should be visible or hidden.

I am aware of how to pass in props from parent-child. What I am unable to figure out is how can i go about making that React-Select disappear? I checked the docs [here](https://react-select.com/props) and there is no such property.

I tried with manually editing the HTML attribute: display = "none" or "block", but it does not seem to change anything.

Here is how it looks like now:

```
<FormGroup row>
    <Col md={6}>
        <Select 
            placeholder={label}
            name={fieldName}
            onChange={method1}
            options={options}
            display="none" />
    </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

I have found a work around this problem for those with similar situation as me, check it out [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3187).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
const customStyles = {
  singleValue: (provided, state) => {
    const display = "none";
    return { ...provided, display };
  }
}
```

```html
<FormGroup row>
  <Col md={6}>
    <Select styles={customStyles} />
  </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

Documentation: https://react-select.com/styles#style-object

Comment: Hi @Shiladitya, this does not work for me, my select field is still showing

Comment: @AKJ can you please create a similar scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by create a similar scenario?

Comment: Hey man, it does not work. Seems like it is broken in terms of accepting the display attriute

Comment: @AKJ How about now? I've updated the answer once again

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to to disappear immediately (provide `shouldDisplay` value yourself):

```js
render() {
  return (
    <FormGroup row>
        <Col md={6}>
            { !shouldDisplay ? null : (
              <Select 
                  placeholder={label}
                  name={fieldName}
                  onChange={method1}
                  options={options}
                  display="none" />
            )}
        </Col>
    </FormGroup>
   )
}
```

Or, if you want some css rules with transition appear, wrap Select with a component which styles you can control.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <FormGroup row>
      <Col md={6}>
        <div style={{display: "none"}}>
          <Select 
              placeholder={label}
              name={fieldName}
              onChange={method1}
              options={options}
              display="none"
          />
        </div>
      </Col>
    </FormGroup>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4:

```
<FormGroup row>
  <Col md={6}>
    <Select className="d-none" />
  </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

For Bootstrap 3:

```
<FormGroup row>
  <Col md={6}>
    <Select className="hide" />
  </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Hi @K K, This does not work at all. for the `className="d-none"` hid all my other dropdown bars. And the `className="hide"` does not work for me either

Comment: @AKJ Are you using any plugin for Select dropdown similar to select2?

Comment: As mentioned above, I am using the React-Select plugin